# JPQL: why i can´t select a record by date?

Tags: java, jpa, sqlite, jodatime, jpql

Im making an app with JPA 2.1, eclipseLink, and a SQLite3 database.

I have a table of clients in which i save the clients birthdates in milliseconds.

In the entity client i use a converter for casting the birthdate value from DateTime (JodaTime) to Long:

```java
@Converter
public class DateTimeConverter implements AttributeConverter<DateTime, Long> {

    @Override
    public Long convertToDatabaseColumn(DateTime arg0) {        
        return arg0 == null ? null : ((DateTime) arg0).getMillis();  
    }

    @Override
    public DateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Long arg0) {       
        return arg0 == null ? null : new DateTime(arg0);
    }
}
```

Im trying to get one of those clients by birthDate in JPQL, but i don´t know how to do it. I tried several things, but none of them worked correctly. For example, i tried to do this:

```java
EntityClient client = new EntityClient();
client.setBirthDate(new DateTime("1966-07-21"));

ArrayList<EntityClient> clientsByBirthdate = new ArrayList<>();

String query = "SELECT o FROM " + EntityClient.class.getCanonicalName() + " o " + 
                    "WHERE o.birthDate = " + client.getBirthDate().getMillis();

for(Object obj : entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList())
    clientsByBirthdate.add(EntityClient.class.cast(obj));
```

But instead of retriving the correct record it retrives all the records with the birthdate set to null.

What im doing wrong?

Comment: From [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) : "Firstly, it holds the datetime as milliseconds from the Java epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z" --> Could this be the reason? (You are asking for 1966)

Comment: I don´t think so. In Joda Time the dates previous to 1970 are represented in negative Longs. For example, `1966-07-21` is `-108867600000`. I already worked with dates previous to 1970, persisting them in the database without any problem. But im so desperate that i will try with a date after 1970.

Comment: What is `birthDate` in your entity - DateTime or Long?

Comment: Well, i test it with a date later than 1970 and throws an exception. So, when i use a date before 1970 i retrieve incorrect records, and i when i use a date after 1970 it throws a PersistanceException.The `birthDate` field in my entity is a `DateTime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use String concatenation to pass parameters to a query. Use parameters:

```
String query = "SELECT o FROM EntityClient o " + 
                "WHERE o.birthDate = :birthDate";
List<EntityClient> list = 
    entityManager.createQuery(query, EntityClient.class)
                 .setParameter("birthDate", new DateTime("1966-07-21"))
                 .getResultList()
```

Comment: You are right. I changed my code to use parameters and now it works perfectly. I'll keep parameters in mind from now on. Thanks a lot!